# How can I change the width or colour of the scrollbar in Chrome?

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome

I'm using the Google Chrome browser on Ubuntu 10.10. It is very difficult for me to see the scrollbar. Is there anyway to make the scrollbar wider or a different colour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go into `System -> Preferences -> Appearance`, click `Customize`, and choose another set of widgets from the list.

Answer (score 1):

The disappearing scrollbar behaviour is enabled through these two packages:

```
overlay-scrollbar
liboverlay-scrollbar
```

Just type `apt-get remove overlay-scrollbar liboverlay-scrollbar`
and you'll get usable scrollbars again.